# How to add fields using formulas

Tags: formula, formula-field

I have a scenario where I need to calculate the cumulative stop time between two sets of date/time fields.
I need to calculate the time when either set has been populated.
Stop Time 1 - Continue  Time 1
Stop Time 2 - Continue Time 2

My current formula only works when all 4 fields are populated. Please help with the formula:

```
(( TIMEVALUE(Continuous_Time_1__c) - TIMEVALUE( Stop_Time_1__c ) )/ 60000) + (( TIMEVALUE( Continuous_Time_2__c ) - TIMEVALUE( Stop_Time_2__c ))/ 60000)
```

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the cumulative stop time between two sets of date/time fields, you can use the following formula:

```
IF(
    AND(
        NOT(ISBLANK(Stop_Time_1__c)), 
        NOT(ISBLANK(Stop_Time_2__c))
    ),
    ((TIMEVALUE(Continuous_Time_1__c) - TIMEVALUE(Stop_Time_1__c))/60000) + ((TIMEVALUE(Continuous_Time_2__c) - TIMEVALUE(Stop_Time_2__c))/60000),
    IF(
        NOT(ISBLANK(Stop_Time_1__c)),
        (TIMEVALUE(Continuous_Time_1__c) - TIMEVALUE(Stop_Time_1__c))/60000,
        IF(
            NOT(ISBLANK(Stop_Time_2__c)),
            (TIMEVALUE(Continuous_Time_2__c) - TIMEVALUE(Stop_Time_2__c))/60000,
            0
        )
    )
)
```

This formula checks if both `Stop_Time_1__c` and `Stop_Time_2__c` are populated, and if they are, it calculates the cumulative stop time between the two sets using the formula you provided.

If one of the `Stop_Time` fields is blank, it calculates the stop time based on the non-blank `Stop_Time` field and its corresponding `Continuous_Time` field. If both `Stop_Time` fields are blank, it returns `0`.